# Geolocation using cell id

Tags: android, geolocation, cellid

My android app should determine approximate phone location using cell id. This is possible using Gears Geolocation API, but I've no idea how to organize the request to Gears server and data exchange. Does anybody have the information about the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Android applications find out their location using `LocationManager`. Gears, to the extent it exists anymore (didn't Google get rid of it recently?), is for a Web site, not an Android app.

Comment: Ok, but what should I do to find out the location of base station (not phone)? As I understand, Gears had huge DB with approximate location of BTSs.

Comment: Well, I've decided my problem using JSON request to https://www.google.com/loc/json. Thanks anyway!